# Concurrency On Association In ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, concurrency

I have an app where people sign up for items.  Each item has a limited number of slots.  How can I handle concurrency?  I've tried like this in the Item class:

```
def sign_up(signup)
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    return 'Sorry, that item is full.' if full?
    signups << signup
    sheet.save!
    nil
  end
end

def full?   
  locked_signups = signups.lock(true).all  
  locked_signups.size >= max_signups
end
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible through AR? Do I need to implement my own locking via a column?  Any suggestions are welcome.

UPDATE: I got this working per tadman's answer.  Here's the code that works:

```
rows_updated = ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
   Item.connection.update "update items set signup_count=signup_count+1 where id=#{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(self.id)} and signup_count<quantity"
end
return 'Sorry, that item is full. Refresh the page to see what\'s still open.' if rows_updated < 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two approaches to this sort of problem that are reliable.

**Counter Column**

You'll create a "remaining stock" column and update it atomically:

```
UPDATE sheet SET signups_remaining=signups_remaining-:count WHERE id=:id AND signups_remaining>=:count
```

You'll have to bind to the `:count` and `:id` values accordingly. If this query runs, it means there was a sufficient number of signups left.

**Reserved Signups**

Create the signup records in advance and allocate them:

```
UPDATE signups SET allocation_id=:allocation_id WHERE allocation_id IS NULL LIMIT :count
```

This will update zero or more signup records, so you'll have to check that you reserved the correct count before committing your transaction.

Comment: With either option, don't we have the same concurrency problem?  A second (third, fourth, etc) user reads the signups_remaining value after the prior user(s) claims a slot (by inserting a new signup row) and before the update to signups_remaining is committed.

Comment: Both of these are reliable because in the first case the query will not return execute if there is insufficient stock, and in the second case you will only claim as many as are currently unassigned. The `WHERE allocation_id IS NULL` ensures that it will not over-write any previous work. This is possible because these are both single atomic statements that either run or don't run. Two separate queries are much harder to synchronize.